# How to run docker/dockerd without systemd and cgroups (debian post install environment)

Tags: docker, installation, debian, systemd, cgroups

**Scenario**

I want to use docker in the `d-i preseed/late_command` stage of my (unattended/headless) debian preseed installation phase.

When I try to start docker with systemd it obviously fails because systemd isn't available.

So I tried running the docker daemon [manually](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/start/#start-the-daemon-manually), however, this fails because the *cgroup* devices are available at that moment.

```
failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

Does anyone have an Idea on how to do this?

**Alternatives**

As an alternative, I thought about doing a "post post installation", i.e. executing the docker command directly on the first reboot after the installation. However, I would prefer to avoid this and do it directly during the installation.